# IE10 SEC7111 notification without mixed content

Tags: https, internet-explorer-10, client-certificates

We have a corporate site that gives a SEC7111 notification in F12 developer tools on the first load. Also it does not show the green bar for the site certificate. When i reload (F5) it will nog give the error again and the certificate bar at the top is green again.

I have researched this error and it all points to mixed content (http/https).

However we have extensively checked and we only have https content. To make it even stranger it seems to be based on the previous page. For example when opening the page from the IE10 default homepage i get a notice it is compromised by http://otf.msn.com/c.gif?rid=3d18a3c7bd554dcf... etc. When i load from another site (a news site in this example) it gives me compromised by a google-syndication ad url. And when opening from a new tab it does not give any errors and shows a green bar.

It might have to do with the fact that we use client certificates for authentication.